# Ionic - How to change Android StatusBarColor?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-statusbar

I got a little problem while working with Ionic. My intention is to change the color of the statusbar on Android devices.

I found some documentation on the Ionic docs, but thy won't work for me...
Maybe I forget or missunderstand something.

Please help me with a blank project step-by-step tutorial how to change the statusbar on Android devices.

Picture tutorial would be nice, but text is also ok. Please don't forget to tell me the files where I need to enter code for the change.

"Please notice that I am using the Ionic framework which means I don't work with Android Studio and don't develope in java!"

Answer (score 2):

put background color in actionabar

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:background="#000" 
     android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

or

also make style for change color of actionbar

```
<style name="Abc" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

     // colorPrimary is actionbar color so you change color code.. 
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is a solution for native android application, but i work with Ionic framework, so i dont develop with java